# tocar varios botones con un dedo

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy queriendo hacer un piano por partes, como podria hacer el efecto de cuando se toca una tecla y dezlizando hacia izquierda o derecha (sin levantar el dedo) suenen las demas notas? 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

casi utilice el mismo codigo de la botonera. Leyendo por ahi tendria que poner otro if con el evento de `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` debajo del `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` ? y mi otra duda es que si no tendria que utilizar MultiTouch en vez de ontouch ya que seria lo logico o no?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton tecla1,tecla2,tecla3,tecla4;
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int son_tecla1, son_tecla2, son_tecla3, son_tecla4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tecla1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib1);
        tecla2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib2);
        tecla3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib3);
        tecla4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib4);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(4).build();
        }else {
            soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        }

        son_tecla1=soundPool.load(this, R. raw.t1,1);
        son_tecla2=soundPool.load(this, R. raw.t2,1);
        son_tecla3=soundPool.load(this, R. raw.t3,1);
        son_tecla4=soundPool.load(this, R. raw.t4,1);

        tecla1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent ) {

                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    soundPool.play(son_tecla1,1,1,0,0,0);
                }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    soundPool.stop(son_tecla1);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        tecla2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent ) {

                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    soundPool.play(son_tecla2,1,1,0,0,0);
                }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    soundPool.stop(son_tecla2);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        tecla3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent ) {

                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    soundPool.play(son_tecla3,1,1,0,0,0);
                }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    soundPool.stop(son_tecla3);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        tecla4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent ) {

                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    soundPool.play(son_tecla4,1,1,0,0,0);
                }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    soundPool.stop(son_tecla4);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Como comentas, en este caso debes implementar la detección de eventos multi touch:

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

---

> como podria hacer el efecto de cuando se toca una tecla y dezlizando
>   hacia izquierda o derecha

De acuerdo a la imagen debes mapear la posición de las teclas (imagenes) y mediante la detección de la coordenada en el eje X podrías saber que tecla estas tocando:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    ....
    //Obtiene posición.
    float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
    float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
}
```

Comment: intente con eso, pero no me suena cuando desliso el dedo (sin soltar) por lo demas botones ... en el Mainactivity implemente el ontouchlistener y me creo un metodo public boolean, luego agrego los botones pero ahora no suena.